# Where does Elseworlds fit into Batwoman chronology?

Tags: arrowverse, chronology, batwoman

The character of Kate Kane, alias *Batwoman* was first introduced to the *Arrowverse* in the 2018 crossover event *Elseworlds*. This episode shows Kate as an established hero who has apparently been working for some time now. This lead to a *Batwoman* TV series which started the following year, and crossed over again with the 2019 crossover event Crisis on Infinite Earths.

The first few episodes of Batwoman are clearly set before Elseworlds, as they show Kate first donning the Batwoman persona. Episode 9 is Batwoman's part of Crisis on Infinite Earths, and so must take place after Elseworlds. Is there any indication, either in the show or from cast and crew comments, where exactly the first crossover is supposed to fit into the timeline?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After Batwoman S01E04 and before S01E05.

From [Caroline Dries](https://twitter.com/carolinedries/status/1188626252174770176?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw%7Ctwcamp%5Etweetembed%7Ctwterm%5E1188626252174770176&ref_url=https%3A%2F%2Fscreenrant.com%2Fbatwoman-tv-show-episode-4-elseworlds-timeline%2F)'s tweet

> After 104 we are officially caught up to Elseworlds!  #batwoman

Later [Russ Burlingame](https://twitter.com/russburlingame/status/1189385064347525120) continued:

> Because the writers wanted to show Kate's origin story, they had to go back to before she was Batwoman, which required some catching-up in the first few episodes. Instead of it being a week between episodes, chronologically speaking, these early episodes have had more time pass.

Also from [CBR](https://www.cbr.com/batwoman-elseworlds-reference/) from 5th epsiode

> Last week, Batwoman showrunner Caroline Dries revealed the show had caught up to "Elseworlds" in the Arrowverse timeline. Now, the show has dropped an explicit reference to last year's crossover event, which introduced Kate Kane to the DCTV universe.
>
> Inthat epsiode Luke is referring to the Flash and Green Arrow's altercation with Dr. John Deegan, which took place at Arkham Asylum.